# css pseudo-element weird behavior

Tags: html, css

I create two pseudo elements with a container div. and I think the container has enough width,while if you press F12 to enter the browser development mode, you will find the second pseudo element is **below** the first one. I thought the two pseudo elements should be in a row . I can't figure it out.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: url('https://i.loli.net/2020/02/27/kd4tgwaMCsx7JW8.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: url('https://i.loli.net/2020/02/27/Hv1jZcd6eCaDUwK.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="box">

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Do you Want it to be below? or do you want it to be side-by-side?

Comment: I thought it should be side-by-side .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pseudo-elements don't have `postion: absolute` and are inline-blocks, like in your case, they (i.e. both of them) need to fit into the width of the main element to be on the same line, otherwise they (i.e. the second one) will wrap to the next line. So you need to make your main element wider:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 110px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: url('https://i.loli.net/2020/02/27/kd4tgwaMCsx7JW8.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: url('https://i.loli.net/2020/02/27/Hv1jZcd6eCaDUwK.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="box">

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, the two pesudo elements are within the .box element, which hasn't been set a width, so I thought the pesudo should expand the width of the .box element ,so the two pesudo element should be in on the same line?

Comment: @Archsx, you're right the `.box` element does not have a width, BUT it's `.container` does have width set to `55px`, which makes the `.box` only able to be as wide as it's container, so the `.box`'s width is `55px`.  That's why the answers below suggest to make `.container` width `110px`.  The answers are correct, you should accept one as the answer.

Comment: so the width of the .box element is determined by the .container and won't be expand by the two pseudo elements? css is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Your container has width: 55px. Change it like this:

```
.container{
  width: 110px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}
```